# Open 2nd modal2 form php file included in modal1 with button code

Tags: php, modal-dialog

calendar.php has buttons to open book.php by selecting Book(button) in calendar date which display time slots (30 minutes) to select and submit for record.

need help to open modal2 for calendar.php
Button code:

```
$calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4>
   <a href ='#dialog2?date=".$date."' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Book</a>";
```

this work but open whole another page, would like to open modal2 on index.php.
Any ideas?

Comment: $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4> <a href ='#dialog2?date=".$date."' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Book</a>";

Comment: Please note that this isn't a forum, as explained in the [tour]. If you want to add additional detail to your question, please use the link marked [edit], not the one marked "add a comment". You might also find the [formatting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) helpful.